# AutoLayout breaks constraints when layoutIfNeeded() is called

Tags: uitableview, swift, autolayout, xcode6

I'm trying to implement a dynamic height `UITaleViewCell` in `UITableView` with XCode6 using Swift.

I laid out my cell as following, by setting up the constraints graphically(Screenshot is from XCode5, because of NDA on XCode6). I also set the BodyLabel's Line Break property to 'Word Wrap', and set the Line number to '0' to allow multiple lines.

[image]

Now if I just set up the cell's contents inside `tableView(tableView: UITableView?, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath?)` method, then I get the dynamic height behavior correctly.

However, since I was following along tutorials available online(specifically [this one](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6KImie4ZMwk&index=2&list=WL)), I added another method to determine the height of the cell with `tableView(tableView: UITableView!, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!)`.
In the tutorial that I was following, it told me to add `cell.layoutIfNeeded()`, so I added that too.

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) -> CGFloat {

    var cell = tableView!.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(kCellIdentifier) as GroupFeedCell

    // Configure the cell
    if let frc = self.fetchedResultsController {
        let feed = frc.objectAtIndexPath(indexPath) as GroupFeed
        cell.titleLabel.text = feed.name
        if let message = feed.message {
            cell.bodyLabel.text = message
        }
    }

    // Layout the cell
    cell.layoutIfNeeded()

    // Get the height
    var height : CGFloat = cell.contentView.systemLayoutSizeFittingSize(UILayoutFittingCompressedSize).height
    return height
}
```

However, when I ran the program, although the table view still displayed the dynamic heights of the cells correctly, it displayed the errors like this:

```
2014-07-27 13:59:22.599 FBGroups[4631:979424] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. Try this: (1) look at each    constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or    constraints and fix it. (Note: If you're seeing NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand, refer    to the documentation for the UIView property translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints) 
(
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x17809e780 H:[UILabel:0x14fd12f50'Body Label Contents...']-(8)-|   (Names:    '|':UITableViewCellContentView:0x178185d70 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x17809e7d0 H:|-(8)-[UILabel:0x14fd12f50'Body Label Contents...']   (Names:    '|':UITableViewCellContentView:0x178185d70 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x17809ea50 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Width' H:[UITableViewCellContentView:0x178185d70(0)]>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x17809e780 H:[UILabel:0x14fd12f50'Body Label Contents...']-(8)-|   (Names:     '|':UITableViewCellContentView:0x178185d70 )>

Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKit/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
```

I tried to figure out what might have gone wrong, and spend good amount of time on it, and I figured out that whenever I delete `cell.layoutIfNeeded()` method, then the constraints error disappears.

And it seemed that among the constraints that are conflicting, `UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Width` was not the one I added, and other than that, the all of the constraints looked innocent to me. I tried to search through what could generate `UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Width` constraints, but I couldn't get the satisfying explanation in my situation. I would like to know what would be the cause of this error message and how to resolve this problem.

Also, can someone explain what would be the purpose of calling `cell.layoutIfNeeded()` method inside calculating height of the cell, and when it would be necessary? Most of the tutorials that were covering dynamic height `UITableViewCell` utilized this method, although my program still displayed cells correctly without that method call, and whenever I tried to use that method, it caused the exceptions.

Comment: I am also having this problem. Did you fixed it?

Comment: have you tried setting the preferredMaximumWidth on the label?

Answer (score 35):

In Xcode, set the priority of the very bottom vertical constraint to 750 (or anything less than a 1000).

Comment: @Tarek, please describe your answer, I don't understand what do you mean. Set priority of what?

Comment: Just select the constraint in your storyboard, then set its priority field in the object inspector.

Comment: Cool! Setting priority for the very bottom vertical constraint to 750 solves the problem.

Answer (score 1):

It could be that the conflicting constraints are because the first two constraints define the width of the label as being 16pts less than the width of the cell, but the third constraint, the `UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Width` wants to make the label a different size.

You might try to lower the values of the content compression resistance/hugging properties to allow the label to ignore its intrinsic size.

Comment: I tried to tinker with that value(decreasing Horizontal hugging priority), but they didn't really fix my problem.

Comment: I have the same problem. Did you ever find a fix for this? Would be really helpful.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like a bug of Apple. I use a work around that add `width` constraint at runtime like this.

```
- (void)configurateBodyLabelConstraint {
    UIScreen *mainScreen = [UIScreen mainScreen];
    CGFloat viewWidth = mainScreen.bounds.size.width;
    CGFloat bodyLabelWidth = viewWidth - 76 - 8;
    NSDictionary *metric = @ {
        @"bodyLabelWidth": [NSNumber numberWithFloat:bodyLabelWidth]
    };

    UILabel *bodyLabel = self.bodyLabel;
    NSArray *constraints = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"[bodyLabel(bodyLabelWidth)]"
                                                                   options:0
                                                                   metrics:metric
                                                                     views:@ {
                                                                         @"bodyLabel": bodyLabel
                                                                     }];
    [self.contentView addConstraints:constraints];
}
```

Answer (score -3):

cell.layoutIfNeeded() - no need to invoke.
Create IBOutlet an NSLayoutConstraint

Comment: Could you add some details to your answer?