# UITableView layout animates on first load

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, nslayoutconstraint

I'm experiencing a strange behaviour in my `UITableView`. In my app when the `UIViewController` that contains the tableView is first shown (`ViewDidLoad`?) all of its elements (from cells to UISearchBar) are animating their sizes and finally get the right dimensions. After that (`ViewWillAppear`...), every time i present this view everything looks good. I'm using Autolayout in Storyboard and it's like the constraints are animating to their proper values. I'm using Swift 1.2, Xcode 6.4 and it's a UITabBar based app. Any ideas what i'm doing wrong? Thanks!

**EDIT**: My `UITableView` uses self-sizing cells with `UITableViewAutomaticDimension` height. It also contains a `UISearchBar`. 

 |search bar| 
|---cell 1---| 
|---cell 2---| 
...

Comment: solition can be this entry http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24984650/autolayout-breaks-constraints-when-layoutifneeded-is-called

Comment: Are you using ios7 or 8? Also does this happen on scrolling as well?

Comment: @jarora I'm using iOS 8 and this doesn't happen on scroll, only on first load. I noticed though the same behavior, in another table view, when I dismiss the keyboard, for the cells that are covered by the keyboard.

Answer (score 0):

This usually happens when there is an animation in progress while the cells in the table view are about to load. Try looking into all the animations in your file and see which animation block is adding those animations to your table view cells.

Also if you are animating constraints using UIView animation block, do call `[self.view layoutIfNeeded]` 
before the animation block and inside the block.