# Collapsable Tableview with Dynamic sizing cells

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, dynamic, nslayoutconstraint

I've been trying to follow [this](https://github.com/jeantimex/ios-swift-collapsible-table-section) github tutorial, however instead of having static cells, they need to be dynamic since I don't know the height at compile time. 
In the tableViewController I have set the `heightForRowAt` to be `0` or `UITableViewAutomaticDimension` depending if the section is collapsed or not. Similar with the `estimatedHeightForRowAt`the value is `0` or a higher value if it's expanded.

Getting to the problem now, I have subclassed the `UITableViewCell` and when the cellForRowAt is called it will add a subview like the following:

```
override func addSubview(_ view: UIView) {
        guard view != nil else {return}

        for view in self.subviews {
            view.removeFromSuperview()
        }

        super.addSubview(view)
        //view.applyLeadingAndTrailingPinConstraint(toSuperview: 0)
        //view.applyTopAndBottomPinConstraint(toSuperview: 0)

        let addedView = self.subviews[0]

        let bottom = NSLayoutConstraint(item: addedView, attribute: .bottom, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self, attribute: .bottom, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
        bottom.priority = 750
        bottom.isActive = true
        NSLayoutConstraint(item: addedView, attribute: .top, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self, attribute: .top, multiplier: 1, constant: 0).isActive = true
        NSLayoutConstraint(item: addedView, attribute: .leading, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self, attribute: .leading, multiplier: 1, constant: 0).isActive = true
        NSLayoutConstraint(item: addedView, attribute: .trailing, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self, attribute: .trailing, multiplier: 1, constant: 0).isActive = true
        NSLayoutConstraint(item: addedView, attribute: .centerX, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self, attribute: .centerX, multiplier: 1, constant: 0).isActive = true
        NSLayoutConstraint(item: addedView, attribute: .centerY, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self, attribute: .centerY, multiplier: 1, constant: 0).isActive = true

        //NSLayoutConstraint.reportAmbiguity(v: self)
        if addedView.hasAmbiguousLayout {
            print("Horizontal: \(addedView.constraintsAffectingLayout(for: .horizontal))")
            print("Vertical: \(addedView.constraintsAffectingLayout(for: .vertical))")
            print("Trace: \(addedView.value(forKey: "_autolayoutTrace"))")
        }
        //addedView.exerciseAmbiguityInLayout()

        //print("self: \(self.frame), subview: \(self.subviews[0].frame)")
    }
```

As you may see, the problem is that there's an ambiguity with the constraints, hence the `hasAmbigousLayout`. When the view is collapsed there is no error. However when I expand the view, **which has also a height constraint**, the ambiguity happens. The following is the output of the 3 print statements inside `hasAmbigousLayout`:

```
Horizontal: []
Vertical: [<NSLayoutConstraint:0x60800028ea10 UIView:0x7fcfe856a790.height == 100   (active)>]
Trace: Optional(
•ViraVira_Info.WellnessCell:0x7fcfe8859a00'cell', MISSING HOST CONSTRAINTS
|   *UIView:0x7fcfe856a790- AMBIGUOUS LAYOUT for UIView:0x7fcfe856a790.minX{id: 776}, UIView:0x7fcfe856a790.minY{id: 771}, UIView:0x7fcfe856a790.Width{id: 778}

Legend:
    * - is laid out with auto layout
    + - is laid out manually, but is represented in the layout engine because translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = YES
    • - layout engine host)
```

I have tried to lower the bottom constraint priority as sugested in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24984650/autolayout-breaks-constraints-when-layoutifneeded-is-called) question. Also I have tried many other sites, which I sadly lost track of.
The result in the app is that the view does not even show up, since it should have a red background, also when i try to print the frame of the subview, the width is 0 which seems odd.

I probably made a silly mistake with the constraint but after 2 days trying I still can't figure it out.

Thanks for your time
-Jorge

Answer (score 0):

There are several issues to note (and may  be part of the problem):

- `override func addSubview(_ view: UIView)` -> I don't think thats the right place for your code. I develop several years now iOS and there was never a reason to override that method. View layout should be done in Interface Builder or in the parent view.
- `guard view != nil else {return}` -> should give you a warning, because view is not an optional (UIView?), so it can't be nil. This check does simply nothing useful.
- `for view in self.subviews { view.removeFromSuperview() } super.addSubview(view)` -> This will remove every previously added view, the last added view will win the race, thats completely unexpected by the caller of addSubview - If a cell adds more than one subview this will cause trouble and headache.
- `let addedView = self.subviews[0]` -> must be equal view, so why not using view in the later code?
- `6 * NSLayoutConstraint` -> A view is normally positioned by 4 constraints, 2 vertical and 2 horizontal - I think you should remove the last two (center constraints) - That may be your problem.

Try to refactor your code...

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but let's go part for part. 1) Maybe it's not necessary to subclass addSubview, however it was the easiest but i will move the constraints to layouSubviews. 2) That was actually a bug, since the value i passed as an argument was an UIView!, and gave me a nil value, which shouldn't be possible but it did happen. 3) I did not know how to create the cellForRowAt so i solved it by adding a subview, which will cause multiple times the same view, so I removed the other one first and then add it again, maybe you can help me find a better solution for this.

Comment: 4) That was just a mistake :). 5) I have tried to do it with 4 only, however it didn't change anything. I still get the same errors.

Comment: 2) You shouldn't fix bugs with workarounds. Try to find the reason for the nil case and fix it. 3)There are already some documentations for tableviews and cell loading. Too much for a comment or answer. see: http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/ios/791/uitableview#t=20170416205904791715